# How to make foreign key by two fields one of which is PK in H2?

Tags: foreign-keys, h2

I would like to define the following relation in H2:

[image]

So that relation connects two elements, but taking their types into acount: each relation type can connect two elements only of given element type.

Unfortunately, I can't draw `FK` from `Relation` to `Element` by two fields, one of fields is automatically dropped only one field remains

Also I can't define additional key in `Elements` table with two fields.

Is this possible in `H2`?

**UPDATE**

The same is in HSQLDB, but with error message.

Target `Element` table is

```
CREATE TABLE ELEM
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    TYP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SPELL VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ELEM_TYP_FK FOREIGN KEY (TYP_ID) REFERENCES TYP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ELEM_ID_TYP_ID_uindex" ON ELEM (ID, TYP_ID);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ELEM_SPELL_uindex" ON ELEM (SPELL);
```

As you see, there is an `UNIQUE` with `(ID, TYP_ID)`

Current relation table is

```
CREATE TABLE REL
(
    LF_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    LF_TYP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    RT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    RT_TYP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TYP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT REL_LF_ID_LF_TYP_ID_RT_ID_RT_TYP_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (LF_ID, LF_TYP_ID, RT_ID, RT_TYP_ID)
);
```

And command to try to relate:

```
ALTER TABLE REL ADD CONSTRAINT REL_LF_ELEM_TYP_FK FOREIGN KEY (LF_ID, LF_TYP_ID) REFERENCES ELEM (ID, TYP_ID);
```

Error message just lies:

> UNIQUE constraint does not exist on referenced columns: ELEM in
>   statement [ALTER TABLE REL ADD CONSTRAINT REL_LF_ELEM_TYP_FK FOREIGN
>   KEY (LF_ID, LF_TYP_ID) REFERENCES ELEM (ID, TYP_ID)]